# Selenium returning the hidden element as visible, clickable and enabled when element is hidden & not clickable

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to open the filters only if they are not already open. For that, I'm checking if "Apply Filter" button is visible/clickable.

To my surprise, I'm getting the element as visible/clickable even though it is not.

Button code mentioned below,

```
<div class="m-t-20 text-left filter-btn-holder ">
   <input type="hidden" id="filterType" value="">
   <button type="button" class="submit btn btn-primary btn-mini filter-focus" id="filterButton" onclick="javascript:getFilteredMedia(true);" "="">Filter</button>
   <button type="button" class="submit btn btn-danger btn-mini" id="filterButton" onclick="clearFilter();">Reset</button>
   <button type="button" class="submit btn btn-mini" data-webarch="toggle-right-side" id="closeButton"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot when the button is visible]

[image: Screenshot when the button is not visible]

Method trying to check if element is clickable

```
public boolean isClickable(WebElement el) 
    {
        try{
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(el));
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

XPath of the button: `xpath = "//button[@id='filterButton' and text()[contains(.,'Filter')]]`

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov which part you want to see, method trying to check clickable is updated in the question. `isDisplayed` is the default method comes with selenium

Comment: Nice, and I would see also how you located the element

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov `xpath = "//button[@id='filterButton' and text()[contains(.,'Filter')]]` this way

Comment: The control definition doesn't contain anything that would make the button invisible or disabled. Try adding dead wait, like 2000 ms and see if it works.

Comment: @NaeemA.Malik I checked multiple times in debug mode where i waited more time to check the conditions like clickable, enabled, visible, everything returned true. Any other options?

Comment: From your pictures even though the text of the button isn't being shown (it's not clear how that is being done from the question) the button still has size on the page which means it is visible and clickable.

Comment: @Thomas if you notice the second screen shot, the button is hidden. How is it clickable, even selenium throws the exception when click command is passed.  Is there any other option to check if the button is visible/clickable.

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy The second screen shot shows the element has dimensions of 62.03 x 21.99 on the page so it's still taking up space on the page - therefore it is visible and potentially clickable -- how exactly are you "hiding" the button.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole There is a Filter button at top of the page which is not shown in the screenshot which hides and unhides the filter options show in the first screenshot. If the element is clickable, the click should happen successfully which is not the case. Only when checking clickable returning true which is actually false

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy "is clickable" is actually "is potentially clickable" - it doesn't actually mean a click will succeed.  For instance if an element is shown on the page but would need to be scrolled to be clicked that would be "potentially clickable" so "is clickable" would return true.  However if when you scrolled there was an overlay element moved to always cover the original element any attempt to click it would actually fail.  When I asked how exactly you are "hiding" the button I meant what is occurring on the page - CSS applied, overlay, etc. not that you click a button to hide it.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole It's the combination of javascript and CSS

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy You're reticence to provide actual detailed information so we can provide a solution for you is staggering. I've explained why you're getting the result you are but without details it's impossible to provide you a solution. Good luck.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I gave all the information I'm aware of. Maybe I'm missing something. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I didn't get the answer exactly, found some workaround. Checked a parent element class if it's visible or not using the javascript executor.

Still not sure why I'm getting visible for an invisible element.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String className = (String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('chat-users').getAttribute('class');");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public boolean isClickable(WebElement el) 
{
    try{
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 6);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(el));
        return el.isDisplayed() && el.isEnabled();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually isEnabled also giving true i.e. it's saying element is enabled

Comment: Then make sure that you proove the right element, otherwise it is clickable ))

Comment: yes, I'm sure I'm passing the right elements which you can see in the screenshots. I'm able to click in another scenario when the filters are opened. Here I'm trying to check if filters are opened, only then I want to click.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the  element with id=__multiselect_mediatag instead of its child elements.

Comment: Sorry didn't get that

Comment: I can see in your screenshot that the filter button you are waiting for is placed inside an <input  id=__multiselect_mediatag> , I was thinking maybe you could play with that instead of its children.

Comment: checked for a parent element class using javascript executor. Found some solution based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. As part of client-side input validation, we provide a box listing all errors found. Of course, the box contains all possible error messages, and we toggle their display from Javascript. However, after filling one input field (and its related error message getting hidden) a new query would report it as still visible.

```
// always returns the same list as the first time it's called
public static List<String> getErrorGroupMsgs(TestState state) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    WebDriver driver = state.getDriver();
    WebElement errorBox = driver.findElement(By.id(state.getProperty("errorBoxGroupId")));
    for(WebElement div : errorBox.findElements(By.tagName("div"))) {
        if(div.isDisplayed()) {
            list.add(div.getDomProperty("innerText").trim());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Adding delays between sending text to the input field and re-reading the displayed messages did not help, but what finally did help was to interleave another call to **findElements()** with different parameters.

```
// returns an updated view of the world
public static List<String> getErrorGroupMsgs(TestState state) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    WebDriver driver = state.getDriver();
    WebElement errorBox = driver.findElement(By.id(state.getProperty("errorBoxGroupId")));
    // this line refreshes the errorBox element so we can get an accurate count below ....
    errorBox.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[display='block']"));
    for(WebElement div : errorBox.findElements(By.tagName("div"))) {
        if(div.isDisplayed()) {
            list.add(div.getDomProperty("innerText").trim());
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```